# Azure - ARM template, locking one specific resource

Tags: azure, devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I wonder if it's possible to add a lock to only one resource (for example storage account) in a resource group. I've tried to do it using ARM template and it always creates lock on a whole resource group. I want to only lock one resource. 
Here is a fragment of a code which I used in a template file:

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks",
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "name": "doNotDelete",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "level": "CanNotDelete",
                "notes": "Storage account should not be deleted."
            }
        }
```

I would appreciate any help in this topic.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do that, use this snippet:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/locks",
    "name": "storageaccountname/Microsoft.Authorization/lockname",
    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "properties": {
        "level": "CannotDelete",
        "notes": "This is an important resource and should never be deleted!"
    }
}
```